# Shared library not found when run from install space

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to install ROS packages on a system using the `catkin_make install` command. Everything builds just fine. Also, when running from the devel space, everything works as expected. However, when running from the install space I get the following runtime error:

```
/home/pr2/ros_ws/install/lib/glugun_laserscanner/glugun_seamfinder_service: error while loading shared libraries: libtensorflow_all.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I know where this shared library and the corresponding header files are located, as can be seen when I print the `TensorFlow_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `TensorFlow_LIBRARIES` in `glugun_laserscanner/CMakeLists.txt`.

```
${TensorFlow_INCLUDE_DIRS}
/home/pr2/TensorFlow/TF_GPU_1_3/tensorflow_bymake/tensorflowinstall/include/google/tensorflow
${TensorFlow_LIBRARIES}
/home/pr2/TensorFlow/TF_GPU_1_3/tensorflow_bymake/tensorflowinstall/lib/libtensorflow_all.so
```

I've tried "installing" them along with all the other stuff from my catkin packages. However, I'm a novice and haven't been able to get it to work. Note, I largely followed [these instruction](https://github.com/cjweeks/tensorflow-cmake)s to build tensorflow (and protobuf and eigen) for use in a cmake project, except I installed them locally instead of system wide.

Any help at getting past the above error would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312001/shared-library-not-found-when-run-from-install-space/) by [kleinma](https://answers.ros.org/users/22806/kleinma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2019-01-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just solved the issue. I copied the contents of the `tensorflowinstall/include` and `tensorflowinstall/lib` folders to `/usr/include` and `/usr/lib`, respectively, and it worked just fine. Not sure if this is the best way to do it. But, it worked.

---

Originally posted by [kleinma](https://answers.ros.org/users/22806/kleinma/) with karma: 48 on 2019-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-01-04**:\

> Not sure if this is the best way to do it

No, that is definitely not a good way to do this.

You're circumventing your platform's package manager and copying files to system-managed directories.

**Comment by [rezenders](https://answers.ros.org/users/37912/rezenders/) on 2021-04-05**:
I am having the same problem, how can it be done using the CMakeList install command?

I tried with this but it didn't work

```
install(TARGETS
    my_package
    ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
    RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)
```